# How to read a batch of records from an EBCDIC file (Mainframe file format) incrementally using C# Dotnet

Tags: c#, .net-core, mainframe, ebcdic

Background:

We have a mainframe file that needs to be parsed and converted into ASCII for further processing.
This mainframe file is of EBCIDC format.
This mainframe file is "Variable Schema Variable Record length" in nature
We have a dotnet parser which reads the records line by line and performs operations as developed

Scenario/Challenge:

We need the command/logic/directions to make the dotnet parser read/fetch batch or records from the source file incrementally.

For e.g -

Read records 1 - 5 from the file in iteration 1
Read records 6 - 10 from the file in iteration 2
Read records 11 - 15 from the file in iteration 3
.
.
.
.
EOF

Current Command - (to read the file line by line basis)

Comment: You **can not** read 4 lines at once, you could read 4 lines sequentially then return them at once but this will not speedup the process. You need to get the **length of the line** before **reading** the line. You can use a **large** buffer to speed up the reading (in java any way). You could also do your own blocking/processing i.e. use an intermediate large block (byte array).

Comment: Why do you need to read 5 records at a time ?   Are you processing htem together or sequentially?  I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Hi @Hogstrom - Thanks for replying. in order to increase the performance i was to read multiple records and then pass each record to a thread (multiprocessing in dotnet). Hence I wanted to do a incremental batch read operation on the file. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're running the system on Windows ... I'd suggest adding a dot net tag for visibility to experts that have experience with dot net.

Comment: how are the 'record' delimited? are they fixed size, do they have a delimiter at the end (like an ascii file would have a \n at the end of each line)

Comment: Hi @ShashankUpadhye, I need to do a similar task. Did you get how to do that?